# Maximum number of vertices of a convex hull generated by some structured finite set

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I'm afraid that the title is not clear. The problem at hand is on the maximum number of vertices of a convex hull generated by the following $2^n$ points:
\begin{align}
\pm\boldsymbol{v}_1\pm\boldsymbol{v}_2\ldots\pm\boldsymbol{v}_n
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{v}_k \in \mathbb{R}^3$. If $n\leq 3$, linearly independent $\{\boldsymbol{v}_k\}$ makes these $2^n$ points be vertices. I guess when $n$ becomes larger only a few of them can be vertices and the others are inside the convex hull (almost certain when considering the two-dimensional analogy). My questions are:

1. Is there any better upper bound on the number of vertices?
2. If the bound is exact, how can we construct such $\{\boldsymbol{v}_k\}$?

Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think your issue can be reformulated into the study of the number of points of the convex hull of the **projection of the standard nD hypercube** into 3D.

Comment: @JeanMarie Indeed. I'll go with this keyword for googling. Thank you!

Comment: Had this issue be in $\mathbb{R^2}$, the result would be $2n$...